# Curl and divergence of magnetic field is zero

Tags: electromagnetism

I am a bit lost. Lets say we have magnetic field $\vec{B}$ for whom

$\nabla \times \vec{B} = 0$

$\nabla \cdot \vec{B} = 0$

I also know that my magnetic field is static. How does one find all forms of $\vec{B}$? I found here and there that $\vec{B}=\nabla \psi$, but I didn't find satisfying proofs. Is it really the only solution?

Comment: you cannot have $\nabla \times \vec{B} = 0$ in all space, somewhere must be *some* source, and then $\nabla \times \vec{B} = \mu_o \vec J$. Only in simple (single connected) domains where $\vec J=0$ is true that $\vec{B} = \nabla \psi $, so this must exclude closed currents.

Comment: What you need is Poincaré lemma: if the curl of $\mathbf B$ is zero everywhere on an open ball then $\mathbf B$ is exact. The null divergence then tells you that the potential (i.e. the scalar field $\psi$ for which $\mathbf B = \nabla\psi$) is harmonic.